# Magento 2 Admin Pages Content

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I'm new to Magento 2 development and am trying to customize some of the content on admin pages and on the "customer account" pages.

Can anyone tell me where the PHP/html code for these is located in the standard file structure? Are there any codeblocks/layouts used for these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento admin pages are mostly built from ui_component ( form, listing ) which requires to understand not only html or phtml , but also knockout js, smarty template , xml and data provider. So nobody can help you with some lines of code or just show you the files you need.